# How to deal with infrequent data in a time series prediction model

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset, missing-data

I am trying to create a basic model for stock price prediction and some of the features I want to include come from the companies quarterly earnings report (every 3 months)  so for example; if my data features are Date, OpenPrice, Close Price, Volume, LastQrtrRevenue how do I include LastQrtrRevenue if I only have a value for it every 3 months?  Do I leave the other days blank (or null) or should I just include a constant of the LastQrtrRevenue and just update it on the day the new figures are released?  Please if anyone has any feedback on dealing with data that is released infrequently but is important to include please share.... Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to put the last quarter revenue in a separate table, with a date field representing when that quarter began (or ended, it doesn't really matter). Then you can write queries to work the way that most suits your application. You could certainly reconstitute the view you mention above using that table, as long as you can relate it to the main table.

You would just need to join the main table by company name, while selected the `max()` of the last quarter revenue table.

Comment: It would be better for organizing the data but not sure how I would process(train) the model with an important data feature that is only available every 3 months. If you suggested using a another regression model for predicting the LastQrtrRevenue daily I dont think that would be a good idea...When the #'s are released it has sudden impact on human investors that could cause rush buying or selling I would want my model to learn. In that case is there any big changes if I leave the column for LastQrtrRevenue as null and only have a value for it every 90 days on the days the #'s are released?

Comment: I see. I was really looking at data management rather than the training model itself. I can see merit in both approaches. The market depends on investor sentiment among other things. Every investor knows the last quarterly numbers when they are released, so in a sense they are a state, as well as an event. So maybe your model need both the quarterly result and the number of days since the last release (or to the next one) to really reflect what is known about the company's performance.

Comment: If i just include the Q #'s every 3 months when they are released and the rest of the dates leave as null will my ANN learn that it is a timely event that can have an impact on the rest of the features that have data daily? Will the ANN be able to make those connections and adjust weights as neccessary on data that is relatively sparse?